# StackOverflowError when using HTTPUrlConnection

Tags: java, sockets, stack-overflow, httpurlconnection

I'm having some trouble using HTTPUrlConnection. The code is basically running in a loop, connecting to a different URL each time, checking the response, and quitting if the response meets some criteria. I'm getting StackOverflowError, but I'm not sure what I have messed up. I tried without using `connection.disconnect()` but to no avail.

Also, do you guys have any tips on speeding up the code below?

Thanks

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:911)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:642)    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1535)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
>     at
>   java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
>     at Main.sendRequest(Main.java:96)   at
>   Main.handleResponse(Main.java:140)

```
public class Main {
    static int counter;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        counter = 0;
        sendRequest("http://192.168.0.1");
    }

    public static void sendRequest(String path) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(path);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();

            if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }

                String response = stringBuilder.toString();
                handleResponse(response);
                inputStreamReader.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            connection.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void handleResponse(String response) {
        String s = response.substring(62,67);
        if (s.equals("Statu")) {
            return;
        } else {
            sendRequest("http://192.168.0.1/" + counter);
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no loop here, but there is a recursion, hence the stack overflow. Try writing the loop you claim already exists.

Comment: your counter is never increased. The recursive call is made before the counter is incremented. Unless the response code is not HTTP_OK (or an exception occurs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A StackOverflowError indicates that your recursive method call of `sendRequest` was sent to often, and there is no more memory left on the Stack.
For a nice explanation see [What is a StackOverflowError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror)
First you should probably check if the places where you break the look (in `handleResponse` and `sendRequest` do work exactly as you expect. Especially the one in `handleResponse` looks wired.
If all that is as it should be you could try to rewrite your logic to use a loop instead of a recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having a StackOverflow, maybe you are doing something wrong, maybe you need more space for the stack.

You can try to increase stack space by means of using this parameter `-Xss`, for example you could try 1 or 2 megas: `-Xss1m`.

If your problem is bad code, you will get your StackOverflowException, no matter how big your stack size would be. I am not an expert oh HttpClient, but I can see your `sendRequest` method calls your `handleResponse` method, and this one calls again `sendRequest`, maybe an infinite loop?

Comment: Yes! It's not an infinite loop, but it should be able to handle a couple of million "loops". I'll try to switch from a recursive call to a loop instead and see what happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The sendRequest and handleResponse call each other and it's possible they do it for much longer ( more iterations) than you think.

If that is indeed the issue ( just log how many times handleRequest invokes sendRequest) you could build a failsafe/limit for handleResponse to stop redirecting to sendRequest if more than X tries have been made.